# Как в MongoDB переименовать "_id" в "id"?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Собственно, вопрос в шапке. Это можно сделать?

Comment: не слышал о такой возможности. Можно лишь продублировать, либо установить свое значение для _id

Comment: как правило, «вопрос в шапке» — это признак плохого вопроса. возможно, в данном случае наличествует проблема «молоток и микроскоп».